# How to change a JButton Icon after using it?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I have a JButton with an image as an Icon, and I want it to change after I have clicked it. However, since it forces me to use try/catch to setIcon, I use it for the contructor, but then, in the actionPerformed method of that button, if I use setIcon again on the JButton variable, it forces me to change the variable to final. If I do it, then I get an error on the constructor and it asks me to remove the final from the JButton variable. Here's what I mean:

```
JButton butoMapa = null;
        try {
            butoMapa = new JButton(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(new File("imatges/Mapa.png"))));
        } catch (IOException e2) {
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }
        butoMapa.updateUI();
        butoMapa.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        butoMapa.setBorderPainted(false);
        butoMapa.setFocusPainted(false);
        butoMapa.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
             public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                 m = entrarFitxer();
                 butoMapa.setIcon(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(new File("imatges/MapaOK.png"))));
             }
        });
```

How can I make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create the `ImageIcon` once and store somewhere e.g. in the class' static field(s). Then just use the fields assigning the images to buttons.

You cna initialize the images in static section or create the images getters which check whether the images ==null and creates them from file.

UPDATE define a method like this

```
public static ImageIcon getImage1() {
  try {
      return new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(new File("imatges/Mapa.png")))
  } catch (IOException e2) {
      e2.printStackTrace();
  }
  return null;
}
```

And use the method for the button creation

```
butoMapa = new JButton(getImage1());
```

Comment: If I do this, it still forces me to set butoMapa as final inside the actionPerformed and not final outside of it

Comment: No, no need to make the class' fields final.

Comment: Well then I don't understand what you mean :(

Comment: I'm doing this but when I want to change it after it is clicked, inside my actionPerformed method it makes me change butoMapa to final

Comment: You can access it ((JButton)evt.getSource()).setIcon()